# I have a Fatal Error with in creation new Module in ZF2

Tags: module, zend-framework2, doctrine

Fatal
Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager::createFromInvokable: failed retrieving "catalogcontrollerindex(alias: Catalog\Controller\Index)" via invokable class "Catalog\Controller\IndexController"; class does not exist
This is my code
Module.php

```html
namespace Catalog;

class Module
{
  public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}


  public function getConfig()
  {
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
  }
}
```

Module.config.php

```html
namespace Catalog;

return array(
 // Doctrine config
    'doctrine' => array(
        'driver' => array(
            __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
            ),
            'orm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                )
            )
        )),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Catalog\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
            // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
            // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
            // using the path /application/:controller/:action
            'application' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/catalog',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Catalog\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
            'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Zend\Mvc\Service\TranslatorServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Catalog\Controller\Index' => Controller\IndexController::class
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'catalog/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/catalog/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
    // Placeholder for console routes
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
            ),
        ),
    ),
 
);
```

Also I have a problem with mapping doctrine with this error
[Exception]
  You do not have any mapped Doctrine ORM entities according to the current c
  onfiguration. If you have entities or mapping files you should check your m
  apping configuration for errors.
please help me

Answer (score 0):

I would have written :

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Catalog\Controller\Index' => 'Catalog\Controller\IndexController'
    ),
),
```

Best

Comment: it works!! great, but still can not maping my doctrine

Comment: Please try to use a factory instead as the new service manager in ZF3 is more efficient and mostly compatible but may not allow invokable anymore

Comment: @Thomas your source for invokables not available in zf3 plz ?

Comment: @Hooli invokables will be available from user perspective, but internally they are gone and replaced with factories